# How can I calculate the width of &statusline as seen on-screen?

Tags: vim

I'm writing a plugin that attempts to take advantage of extra whitespace in the statusline by displaying information of arbitrary length.  Depending on the status of the current buffer, I want to display a specific slice of this information.

- I can grab the format string of `&statusline`, however this length can greatly differ from the actual on-screen length after all processing is done.
- `%<` and friends won't help me here because I would possibly need to truncate from both ends of the string if the information I want to see is in the middle.  I can determine what section of the string I want via the current status of the active buffer.

Is there any way for me to grab the processed statusline via vimscript so I can alter it and make smart decisions based on it's length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ask your question on vim mailing list.

If there is a trick to grab the expanded statusline, it's more likely that someone there will know it. (BTW, don't forget that elements may be right justified.)

You may have to play with `winwidth()` and to expand the official statusline by yourself to operate your alteration.

Comment: I have asked on vim_use and gotten no response.  Maybe I could crosspost to vim_dev?  Parsing the statusline option and calculating everything possible in it myself would be insane and probably very slow.  The current implementation uses `winwidth()` and does some really rough and crappy guessing, however if I can't find an answer to this question, it will likely all get scrapped.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid there is no simple solution.

Comment: Going to go ahead and award this to you.  From everything I've gathered, parsing the &statusline option and expanding it on my own would indeed be the only way to achieve this.  Still no answers on vim_dev :/.